# ¿Cómo hacer que mi input text agregue separación cuando yo ingrese un número de teléfono en Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, input, numberformat

Buen día, estoy intentando hacer un input en Angular 8 en el cual cuando yo agregue un número de teléfono (ejemplo: 5544332211), en el input se vaya agregando espacios automáticamente "55 44 33 22 11", no necesito que se formatee el valor (de hecho así tengo que guardar el valor en la base de datos '5544332211'), solamente que sea visual el formato.

Estuve investigando en la documentación de Angular si hay algún Pipe o algo similar pero no encontré algo que pudiera utilizar.
Sería de mucha ayuda si me pudieran ayudar, ya que soy nuevo en Angular.

Estuve investigando y encontré lo que necesito hecho en JavaScript:

```js
// Campo numeros
var numeros = document.getElementById('numeros');

// Poner cursor en el campo numeros
numeros.focus();

numeros.onkeydown = function(e){
 // Permitir la tecla para borrar
 if (e.key == 'Backspace') return true;

 // Permitir flecha izquierda
 if (e.key == 'ArrowLeft') return true;

 // Permitir flecha derecha
 if (e.key == 'ArrowRight') return true;

 // Bloquear tecla de espacio
 if (e.key == ' ') return false;

 // Bloquear tecla si no es un numero
 if (isNaN(e.key)) return false;
};

numeros.onkeyup = function(){
 numeros.value = numeros.value
     // Borrar todos los espacios
     .replace(/\s/g, '')

     // Agregar un espacio cada dos numeros
     .replace(/([0-9]{2})/g, '$1 ')

     // Borrar espacio al final
     .trim();
};
```

```html
<label>Numeros de 2 digitos</label>
<input type="text" id="numeros">
```

He intentado pasar el código a Angular pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo, estuve intentando con el evento keyup de Angular, pero no me funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adaptación del código a Angular:

**app.component.html**

```
<input type="text"   (keydown)="keyDownEvent($event)" 
(keyup)="keyUpEvent(numeros)" #numeros/>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent  {



 textoSinFormato: string;

  keyDownEvent(e){
    // Permitir la tecla para borrar
    if (e.key == 'Backspace') return true;

    // Permitir flecha izquierda
    if (e.key == 'ArrowLeft') return true;

    // Permitir flecha derecha
    if (e.key == 'ArrowRight') return true;

    // Bloquear tecla de espacio
    if (e.key == ' ') return false;

    // Bloquear tecla si no es un numero
    if (isNaN(e.key)) return false;
  }

  keyUpEvent(numeros){

    numeros.value = numeros.value
                // Borrar todos los espacios
                .replace(/\s/g, '');

       //guardar texto sin formato en la variable textoSinFormato
       this.textoSinFormato = numeros.value;

       numeros.value = numeros.value
                // Agregar un espacio cada dos numeros
                .replace(/([0-9]{2})/g, '$1 ')

                // Borrar espacio al final
                .trim();

  }

}
```

Hice una pequeña modificación al metódo `keyUpEvent()` para que después de remover todos los espacios guarde el valor en la variable `textoSinFormato`, para que esté listo para guardar.

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba. En verdad muchas gracias.